# How to detect lines arranged in a visual pattern in an image?

Tags: image-processing, pattern

I have a black and white image like this:

[image]

Visually, there is a clear pattern of black lines evenly separated by somewhat thicker white lines. The problem I need to solve is to automatically detect the black lines and generate the corresponding vector lines for each. What software/library/algorithm can I use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

If it is a true bw-image, i.e. it contains binary values only, you can use the Hough transform for circles (or a special one for ellipses). In the Hough space you will find maxima for the coordinates of the center and the radius or radii, respectively. If necessary, you can use a statistical test to proof the maxima since there are offen multiple local maxima.